# Graphing a plane

Tags: plotting

I am trying to figure out how to graph a plane in *Mathematica*. This is what I am trying to graph, but nothing seems to show up in the output -- just an empty box. I've tried adjusting a lot of stuff but still nothing. Any hints? As you can probably tell i am very new to *Mathematica*.

```
L[x_, y_] = -5 x + 3 y - 4;
TanPlane = Plot3D[L[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
PlotRange -> {-5, 20}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Your code works fine for me as is.  Are you starting with a clean kernel?  Go to Evaluation > Quit Kernel > Local and select it;  this will clear everything from memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have values assigned to one or more of `x`, `y`, `z`. To avoid having those substituted into your expressions, use

```
{x, y, z} = Range[3]; (* just to make sure code is safe *)
L[x_, y_] := -5 x + 3 y - 4
Plot3D[L[x, y], {x, -10, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
  PlotRange -> {-5, 20}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: I would add to @m_goldberg's solution:  `ClippingStyle->None`.  (Also be sure to add a semicolon after the definition of `L[ ]`).

Comment: could you explain what the first line does? ive not seen that

Comment: @StillLearningToCode. It sets `x` to 1, `y` to 2, and `z` to 3. It is not really needed, but it keeps me honest, making sure that I am not taking advantage of variables being  unassigned. `Range[3]` returns `{1, 2, 3}`. _Mathematica_ allows parallel assignment  between lists. You can do things like swapping variables (i.e.,  `{x, y} = {y, x}`) safely in _Mathematica_.